# Non Object Notice Error - How to fix please

Tags: wp-admin, errors, body-class

No doubt I'm missing something obvious here...

The following code to add a body class to an admin page is producing this error notice:

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../box.php on line 103`

How to get rid please. Thanks in advance!

```
public function admin_body_class($classes) {

  global $wpdb, $post;

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    /* Line 103 */ if ($post->post_parent > 0 ) { 

      $status = 'child-';

    } else {

      $status = 'parent-'; 

    }

    $classes .= ' ' . $status . $screen->post_type;

    return $classes;

}
```

Comment: Which line is 103?

Comment: please do the minimum of debugging before to ask a question. that means looking at every variable to see if the contains the expected values and writing these values in the question. look also this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: @laxmana - that would help wouldn't it! :) - Code updated to show line 103

Comment: Try to put that if condition under `if(isset($post))` to see if your $post variable is actually get set or not.

Comment: @mmm I already did - hence me asking the question. Thank you for the resource though.

Comment: @Shrikant D - This works!!! Thank you **Hi5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with as mentioned below:

```
public function admin_body_class($classes) {

    global $wpdb, $post;

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    $status = 'parent-';
    if( isset( $post->post_parent ) && $post->post_parent > 0 ) {
        $status = 'child-';
    }

    $classes .= ' ' . $status . $screen->post_type;

    return $classes;

}
```

Comment: Awesome - was just in the process of updating the post to show your answer :)